# 'TableList' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: list, jupyter-notebook

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Ayush ShaZz\Desktop\Code_Python\FoodCaloriesList.pdf",pages='all',multiple_table='true',flavor='lattice')

tables.to_excel("tableExcel.xlsx")
```

How to save these tables into the Excel ??
Excel should be like

```
Table1 <space> Table2 <space>.....
```